# how do I correct dc offset with torchaudio high pass filter?

Tags: python, audio, scipy, signal-processing, torchaudio

I am segmenting drum audio files at each transient and exporting the audio to individual wav files. The problem is, all of my files have a dc offset that I cannot seem to get rid of which is causing popping sounds at the end of the file. I am able to use Audacity's built in high-pass filter to verify that applying a filter would fix my problem, but I have not yet been able to replicate those results with code.

My preference is to use torchaudio's highpass_biquad() method but I am open to using scipy filters too. The main goal is to remove the offset so that the audio files do not have a popping sound at the end.

How do I implement a high pass filter to correct the dc offset like Audacity's high pass filter does as shown in the pictures?

**torchaudio approach**

```
from torchaudio.functional import highpass_biquad
import librosa

wav, sample_rate = librosa.load(path, sr=None, mono=False) # files are 24 bit 44.1k
wav_tensor = torch.from_numpy(wav)
cuttoff_freq = 15.0

wav_filtered = highpass_biquad(wav_tensor, sample_rate, cutoff_freq)
```

**scipy approach**

```
from scipy import signal
import librosa

wav, sample_rate = librosa.load(path, sr=None, mono=False) # files are 24 bit 44.1k
cutoff_freq = 15

# METHOD 1
b, a = signal.butter(N=5, Wn=cutoff_freq, btype='high', fs=sample_rate)
wav_filtered = signal.filtfilt(b, a, wav)

# METHOD 2
sos = signal.butter(N=5, Wn=cutoff_freq, btype='hp', fs=sample_rate, output='sos')
wav_filtered = signal.sosfilt(sos, wav)
```

Picture 1 is the output of torch highpass_biquad method. The scipy approach yields similar results.

Picture 2 is the audio after applying highpass effect in audacity. This is the desired output of my code.

Picture 3 is an example of output with no high pass filtering applied. Most files come out centered below 0dB.

[image: result of torch highpass_biquad. Similar results as scipy approach.]

[image: audio after applying highpass effect in audacity. This is the desired output of my code]

[image: Example of output with no high pass filtering applied. Most files come out centered below 0dB]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the dc offset was produced by a scaling function in wavio when writing the file. The highpass filters were working correctly after all.